# Web Scraping of span tag in div class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
r = requests.get("https://www.typingtest.com/test.html?textfile=tiger.txt&minutes=1&mode=text&result_url=result.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
lst = soup.find('span', {'class': 'test-text-area-font-highlighted'})

for i in lst:
    print(i.text)
```

But it show the following error:
for i in lst:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Please describe what are your goals, what you've tried to get there and what are the obstacles on the way.

Comment: My goal is to get the highest typing speed score on the website.
No matter what text is given. That's why I tried to extract the text of that webpage and copy those contents in a file and then I will use the pyautogui to type the following text

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. There is no `<span>` element with a class name of `test-text-area-font-highlighted`, Thus `lst` is going to be `None`.

2. The `find()` function returns only the first matching element (which has a type of `bs4.element.Tag`), and therefore is not iterable.

So, try to find the correct class name of the `<span>` element and use the `find_all()` method instead.

Comment: Oo I typed it mistakely, its div but still I can't find out following class. Is it because of a pseudo element=> ::before?

Comment: Wait, no there is <span> tag.
Read the whole line not just half of it

Comment: Let me check you second advice

Comment: With find_all(), it doesn't give any error but instead no result